# Bounds between the eigenvalues and the diagonal elements of a semidefinite positive matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a bound(s) of the eigenvalues of a symmetric semi-definite positive matrix given the values of the diagonal elements? I could see already that some people referred here to the Schur's majorization theorem but I want to know if there are additional inequalities or references that can help to estimate the eigenvalues from the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your matrix is positive semdefinite doesn't add anything meaningful to the case of arbitrary symmetric matrices. In addition to Schur's majorization theorem, you might find the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Omno's answer, Horn showed (1954) the converse of the Schur's theorem (1923); that is, there are no additional inequalities (or equalities) linking $spectrum(A)$ and the $(a_{i,i})$  which are algebraically independent of the relations produced by Schur.